# Grammar of "I would quickly sabotage close-up whatever..."

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Excerpted from [the-tls.co.uk](http://www.the-tls.co.uk/articles/public/80834/):

> I was too afraid that I would quickly sabotage close-up whatever good impression I might have managed to create long-distance.

I can understand the sentence above, but its structure is strange to me.
"*I would quickly sabotage whatever good impression I might have...*" is normal, but when added **close-up** I am confused, it seems it just sticks an extra noun into a complete sentence.

Can someone show me some sentences with similar structure (Verb + extra noun + Object)? What kinds of nouns can I use in this way?

Comment: *Close-up* and *long-distance* are not nouns in this sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Close-up* here is not used as a noun but as a locative, contrasting with *long-distance* at the end of the sentence.

The phrase is composed of the adjective *close* plus the intransitive preposition or particle (or adverb if your grammar is traditionalist) *up*, with the sense "completely, all the way", as in *fill up*. Compare the phrase with the opposite meaning *far away*.

The noun *closeup* in fact derives from this phrase: it's a shot taken from a position *close up to the actor*.

I personally would not hyphenate either *close up* or *long distance* in these adverbial uses; but that doesn't make the author's use wrong.

Comment: Can I say "I would eat near here a cake" to indicate location?

Comment: @CYC *near here* is fine, but we do not ordinarily put adverbs or locatives between a verb and its object: *I would eat a cake near here*, or *Near here I would eat a cake*. It is placed before the object here only because a) the object clause is very heavy and b) to parallel the position of contrasting *long distance* at the end of the object clause.

Comment: So the sentence in question has an uncommon structure? it puts "close-up" between sabotage and its object.

Comment: @CYC W e l l . . . it has a structure licensed by uncommon content!

Comment: The hyphen in close-up is a warning against trying parse the sentence grouping "up" with "whatever". Personally I would probably have marked the phrase with commas, and re-written the ending: "... I would quickly sabotage, close up, what I might have managed to create *at a distance*."

Comment: @alephzero Understood; but there's another garden path when you hyphenate, which is parsing *close-up* as an adjectival; and the commas suggest that *close up* is a supplement rather than integrated. Me, I'd write "I was afraid that close up I would &c"

Comment: @StoneyB To avoid any and all twisty paths, the writer needed only to reverse the word order: _I was too afraid that I would quickly sabotage up close..._

Answer (score 5):

This seems like shorthand use of adverb clauses:

> I was too afraid that I would quickly sabotage **(in a)** close-up **(situation/meeting)** whatever good impression I might have managed to create **(in)** long-distance **(communication)**.